# How to hide an element or div of website only on Internet Explorer?

Tags: hide, element

I have an element on my website which is displaying well in all the other sites except Internet Explorer and I would like to hide it only on internet explorer.. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [window.navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator) to identify the browser being used by the user of your site.
And then you can use [visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp) property or [display](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp) property in javascript after detection of browser to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an IE conditional comment to wrap the element. Since only IE understands conditional comments, only IE will hide the element.

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <element>
    </element>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($.browser.msie == true)
  {
    alert(1);
  }
});
```